# How to retrieve class object from ICollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 2 classes `Users` and `Userdetails`.

`User` contains `Userdetails ICollection`;

```
public class Users
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<Userdetails> Userdetails;
}
```

I want to retrieve a `UserDetails` object from a `User` object but could not find a way;

I have implemented it in this way:

```
var  lstUserdetails = new List<Userdetails>();
lstUserdetails = (from e in user.Userdetails
                      select e).ToList();
var userobject = ((Userdetails)lstUserdetails.Find(x=>x.id == Id));
```

but it is showing `userobject` null.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe there's just no `Userdetails` with `id == Id`?

Comment: Also, the LINQ query is useless as the cast in the last line is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userDetailsObejct = (from u in user.UserDetails 
                         where u.id == Id
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return a UserDetails object from the UserDetails collection from a specified user with an id that's equal to Id. If it doesn't find it, it will return null.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var  lstUserdetails = new List<Userdetails>();
lstUserdetails = (from e in user.Userdetails where e.id == Id 
                  select e).Firstordefault();
```